# Delphi FMX NumberBox missing floating point on Android 4.4 and less

Tags: delphi, input, floating-point, firemonkey, android-4.4-kitkat

I have an interesting problem. I use the `TNumberBox` component to input floating point numbers in my Android application.

If the application is run on Android 5.1 and higher, it works fine.  But on Android 4.4, if the user clicks on the NumberBox, it shows a keyboard without any decimal key, so it is impossible to insert floating point numbers!

I tried to compile the application in Delphi XE7 with Android SDK 4.4, and in Delphi 10.1 Berlin with Android SDK 7.0, but the result is the same.

Is this a bug? How I can quickly fix this issue?

Comment: does it's the same with Tedit and KeyboardType = NumbersAndPunctuation ?

Comment: I would think it's an OS bug which was eventually fixed. After all, I assume you're using the default keyboard provided by the OS, and not some custom keyboard.

Comment: Yes it is standard keyboard from OS.
KeyboardType is NumberPad. If I select other type as NumbersAndPunctuation is posibly to insert floating point numbers but  characters too. It isnt very nice solution.
In latest Android versions is problem fixed but many users still have 4.4 KitKat

Comment: @Jerry - yes of course.  The most likely explanation is a bug in Android which means that applications requesting a decimal number input only get integer.  Or is it more likely that the FireMonkey framework is not working correctly on certain versions of Android ?  I know which *I* think is more likely.  The *TVirtualKeyboardType* enum in FireMonkey doesn't even come *close* to representing the range of possibilities offered by the Android *InputType*.  That's what you get for targeting lowest common denominator.

Comment: Any ideas to final solution ?